# Error creating bean with name 'batchConfigurer' in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a spring batch written using Spring boot. My batch only reads from MongoDB and prints the record.
I'm not using any SQL DB nor have any dependencies declared in project but While running it I'm getting below exception:

```
s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'batchConfigurer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/batch/BatchConfigurerConfiguration$JdbcBatchConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'batchConfigurer' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-06-01 10:43:39.485 ERROR 15104 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

 ***************************
 APPLICATION FAILED TO START
 ***************************

 Description:

 Parameter 1 of method batchConfigurer in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchConfigurerConfiguration$JdbcBatchConfiguration required a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' that could not be found.
- Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.datasource.jndi-name) did not find property 'jndi-name'
- Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'javax.transaction.TransactionManager'


 Action:

 Consider revisiting the conditions above or defining a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' in your configuration.
```

In my pom.xml I've added below dependancies:

```
spring-boot-starter-batch
spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb
spring-boot-starter-test
spring-batch-test
```

Here's my batch configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Bean
    public Job job() throws Exception {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job1").flow(step1()).end().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1() throws Exception {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<BasicDBObject, BasicDBObject>chunk(10).reader(reader())
                .writer(writer()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemReader<BasicDBObject> reader() {
        MongoItemReader<BasicDBObject> reader = new MongoItemReader<BasicDBObject>();
        reader.setTemplate(mongoTemplate);
        reader.setCollection("test");
        reader.setQuery("{'status':1}");
        reader.setSort(new HashMap<String, Sort.Direction>() {
            {
                put("_id", Direction.ASC);
            }
        });
        reader.setTargetType((Class<? extends BasicDBObject>) BasicDBObject.class);
        return reader;
    }

    public ItemWriter<BasicDBObject> writer() {
        MongoItemWriter<BasicDBObject> writer = new MongoItemWriter<BasicDBObject>();
        return writer;
    }

}
```

Here's is my launcher class:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)
public class MyBatchApplication {
...
}
```

Comment: version of spring boot u are using? I don't think it should try to autoConfigure jdbcAutoConfiguration as ur using mongo db.

Comment: I'm using 2.0.1.RELEASE version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Batch requires the use of a relational data store for the job repository.  Spring Boot enforces that fact.  In order to fix this, you'll need to add an in memory database or create your own `BatchConfigurer` that uses the Map based repository.  For the record, the recommended approach is to add an in memory database (HSQLDB/H2/etc).

Comment: Even after adding H2 DB it gives the same error. Do u have any sample for Spring batch using Spring boot for Mongo DB?

Comment: I forgot to remove the "(exclude = DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)". It works now. Thanks.